# Intel assembly syntax OFFSET

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, nasm, masm

Now that i know u can use gcc for Intel syntax instead of default at&t with

> gcc -S -masm=intel test.c

There is this line

> mov DWORD PTR [ebp-16], OFFSET FLAT:base

Is it the same as `mov dword[ebp-16], base`?
Otherwise what must i do?

Comment: Yes, in NASM. No, in MASM. And this is MASM syntax, as evidenced by the `OFFSET` keyword, but you tagged it NASM, so which do want to know?

Comment: Hello @harold i'm programming in nasm thats why i tagged nasm. I wanted to know how to do this masm code in nasm and what offset flat:base mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `mov dword [ebp - 16], base` is correct NASM syntax to store the label address to 4 bytes of memory at EBP-16.

I haven't seen `offset flat:` for a while - I think it's obsolete, but it's what GAS's idea of `.intel_syntax noprefix` used to demand (I had to look at Gas's source code to find that out).  `gcc -masm=intel` uses it when using symbol addresses as immediates, but `offset base` works, too, in GAS.

It means the same as `offset` to MASM, or the unadorned variable name in NASM.

Comment: I love Stack Overflow, just made my life a lot easier. Again. <3

Comment: GNU assembler (GAS) `.intel_syntax noprefix` is not AT&T syntax at all.  The GNU assembler's default `.att_syntax` is compatible with the syntax AT&T used for their x86 Unix assembler, but `.intel_syntax noprefix` was a more recent addition to GAS that doesn't derive from anything AT&T designed.